# how to upload .csv file to azure folder in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

Anyone know to to upload a .csv file to a folder inside a blob container in python?
i'm having difficulty trying to acess the folders inside it.
i have the csv and want to save it inside the blob folder, but it didn't work.
the file is in code, so i dont want to pass the directory where it is.

```
csv = df.to_csv()
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name, 'folder/csv/mycsv/' , csv)
```

Someone knows how i can save the csv directly to the folder inside the storage folder (folder/csv/mycsv/) in azure?

i got an error stat: path too long for Windows

Comment: How about you shorten your path?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation of [`DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), I believe `csv` variable actually contains `string` type data. If that's the case, then you will need to use [`create_blob_from_text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice.blockblobservice?view=azure-python-previous#create-blob-from-text-container-name--blob-name--text--encoding--utf-8---content-settings-none--metadata-none--validate-content-false--progress-callback-none--max-connections-2--lease-id-none--if-modified-since-none--if-unmodified-since-none--if-match-none--if-none-match-none--timeout-none-) method.

So your code would be:

```
csv = df.to_csv()
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_text(container_name, 'folder/csv/mycsv/' , csv)
```